# Using FileGDB in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to load an ESRI FileGDB of USDA gSSURGO data into QGIS, but I'm having some trouble. I followed the instructions at KyngChaos.com to compile GDAL 1.11 and add the FileGDB plugin (running QGIS on OS 10.11). So I'm able to go to "Add Vector Layer - Directory - ESRI FileGDB," but when I load the GDB I don't get individual layers. I just get a layer that appears to have an attribute table and no feature types (see image). Not sure what's happening. I've seen a few similar questions that made me think there are just too many fields, perhaps. There are 56. [image]

Very new to QGIS and very rusty on my GIS skills.

Comment: Have tried the OpenFileGdb driver? It will read version 9.x while ESRIfilegdb will not read 9.x versions.

Comment: @klewis The same thing happens with OpenFileGDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you opened, Value Added, does not have geospatial features. It is meant to be joined to MUPolygons, on the MUKEY field. In your download Soils folder look for a much larger zip file, probably around 1 gigabyte or larger. This file geodatabase contains the Soils polygon, etc. I have QGIS 2.14.3 32bit and I can view all the data layers using the OpenFilegdb driver.[image: QGIS_gssurgo]

Comment: Thanks! I have been able to load the other GDB with OpenFileGDB. Hadn't thought of joining. Will give that a shot. Oddly enough I'm working with WY data.